# After rearraning displays, the mouse buttons stop working

Tags: display, settings, mouse

I just installed eOS and tried to rearrange the screens. Once I rearrange the displays in the menu, so that my main display is to the right and not to the left, the mouse buttons stop working.

I have two matching LG displays and also tried the LXRandR app, but the effect was the same. 
Once you rearrange the displays, you can only move the mouse cusor but the buttons don't work. The keyboard still works and I was able to return to the previous settings this way.

Mouse: Logitech M215, Keyboard Logitech K330

It doesn't happen if you log out/ restart so I guess it's a problem with the desktop enviroment.

I hope you can suggest a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: I have same issue with HP monitor and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I have more clues, this issue is happening when extended screen mode is in use, if you press Win+P or Cmd+P it changes to use external monitor only and everything starts to work fine, also in duplicated screen mode or only integrated screen mode. Only when extended screen mode is activated buttons of mouse are not responding.

Answer (score 0):

It got even worse. I now cannot login anymore. If you try to click on the login button it jumps from the right to the left screen. If I use the keyboard to type the password and press enter it doesn’t login but show the same login screen again.

I will probably delete the installation today and switch to Ubuntu. Quite unfortunate since for the time it worked I quite liked eOS